# How to typeset the set of real numbers

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

I want to use a command to write the set of real numbers as `\mathbb{R}`. I've seen that many authors use `\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}`. But shouldn't one use `\DeclareMathOperator{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}` instead? Because this should give the correct spacing.

Comment: It's an ordinary symbol, `\DeclareMathOperator` is not the right tool and would give *incorrect* spacing.

Comment: **R** does not want Operator spacing, it is not like `\sin` in sin x that takes a following argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a little bit off-topic. Here is an example why you wouldn't want `\DeclareMathOperator` for ordinary symbols.

Before I knew that `\DeclareMathOperator` is not for symbols, I used to apply it to define `\Id`. Thus seems to be fine, until one day I wrote `\Id \otimes f`, and found that the spacing between `\otimes` and `f` is unexpectedly small, see the picture for comparison:

[image]

Thus you should have a clear mind which type your math command is: symbol, operator, binary relation...

---

Below is the code for generating the image above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}

\begin{document}

\( \Id \otimes f \) (using \verb|\DeclareMathOperator|)

\( \mathrm{Id} \otimes f \) (correct result)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm a bit confused. If I define a new logarithm, I would definitely use something along `\DeclareMathOperator{\newLog}{log}` and not newcommand. In this situation `\newLog \otimes f` would yield the same spacing as in your example. But isn't this the correct way?

Comment: @KuSi No, it's not, because you shall never encounter this mathematically. Unless `log` here is used as a noun rather than a function, in which case you need to define it as a symbol.